# Should I install my split AC outdoor unit further away so it's in the shade?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

So i just got a 1.5TR split AC (LG LS-H18VNXD) and i have two options.

Install the otudoor unit (ODU) just behind the indoor unit (IDU) on the outer wall, so piping distance would be **minimum** possible, 
But the ODU faces the sun directly.
**OR**
Install the ODU ***12 feet away*** from IDU (pipe will have ***two 45 degree curves***), but ODU will be cool and shady place.

Which one will be more efficient and by how much ? Please advice.

**Optional questions:** 
If the answer is shade one, do i need additional gas recharge (the ac comes with 1kg r32 prefilled). 
Also I am planning to make a air filter for the ODU as it comes with naked fins and there are lot of bugs around, will it be fine ?

Don't know the installation guy will be honest so asking it here. Thanks :)

Comment: What type of traffic would be over/near the additional 12 feet of piping?

Comment: Can you route that additional lineset length *inside* the conditioned space?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the splits I have installed are pre charged for approx 15’ of line set. I looked on line and did not see much in the way of assistance.
 1kg is a small charge  I would be expecting closer to 2 kg based on the systems I have installed. I usually suggest the easiest location for maintenance is there already a receptacle mounted in either location this could save some $ as a receptacle is required by the national electric code. If you plan on issuing your system for heat in the winter the location really will not matter a large amount because any location effect gained in summer may be lost in winter.

Comment: Presumably the receptacle for these units is inside near the air handler, right? Does a unit charged for 15' of refrigerant lines come with sufficient electric power and control wires for 15'?

Comment: The receptacle is required to be at the compressor outside, all of the units I have installed in the last 3 or 4 years are powered by the outdoor unit, prior to that 2 sources of power were needed for some models. As to the charge comes with the unit it varies even between models but the install nstructions normally state what charge is needed , I can figure it out it’s superheat and sub cooling but it’s a lot faster if the mfg states the normal charge with a given unit / lineset